# how to integrate arbor.js in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, integrate, arbor.js

I need to add arbor.js in my ruby on rails project for graphs visualization

I change the gemfile adding the gem: gem 'arbor-rails', '~> 0.0.4', and then do a bundle install.

Also, in my vendor/assets/javascript/ add a file called arbor.js with the arbor.js data from https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor

In my app/assets/javascripts/application.js I add the line //= require arbor

With all that, it´s supposed to work fine. I use the next example for a simple graph:

https://gist.github.com/RC1140/1036344/01df1354ada1de2c0cc0b0b916cd4117ff14bf47

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

[arbor-rails](https://github.com/mockdeep/arbor-rails) has not seen any update for 4 years.

Try to remove remove the gem from the gemfile and run `bundle update`.

Putting the javascript file in `vendor/assets/javascript/`  and requiring it in

`app/assets/javascripts/application.js` should be enough.